# Is it possible to launch theme settings or power save mode settings page?

Tags: windows-phone-8

As subject said, is there have a way to launch theme settings page or power save mode settings in my app? I can't find these URI schemes for launching built-in apps in MSDN.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662937(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not.

There are no URI schemes for these settings pages. The link you provide lists all of them that are available.